# 404 при запросе к MS Face API

Tags: python, requests, микросервисы

делаю post запрос с целью получить статус тренировки группы лиц в MS Face API, но получаю ошибку 404, вот документация и этот кусок кода (вставил неработающий ключ в код):
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395247

```
key = '3500bf4fe5704b0b9340a811b4727e18'
def train_status(group):
    url = 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/persongroups/' + str(group) + '/training'
    print(url)
    headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key}
    params = {'personGroupId': group}
    response = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

В документации написано, что нужен метод `GET`, а у вас `POST`.
Попробуйте:

```
response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
```

Comment: да, спасибо, уже нашёл)